# Errors when trying to install a Conda Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, anaconda

When attempting to install a Conda environment , i am hit with a huge series of errors.  It seems that I have a lot of conflicts, but not sure exactly what i should delete / change / etc to fix it .

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package python conflicts for:
pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0,>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
matplotlib=3.0.0 -> numpy -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
nb_conda -> nb_conda_kernels[version='>=2.0.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> prometheus_client -> twisted -> service_identity -> attrs[version='>=16.0.0'] -> hypothesis -> enum34 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
numpy=1.15.2 -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
python=3.5
scipy=1.1.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0,>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
Package setuptools conflicts for:
scipy=1.1.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0,>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
numpy=1.15.2 -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
nb_conda -> nb_conda_kernels[version='>=2.0.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> prometheus_client -> twisted -> service_identity -> attrs[version='>=16.0.0'] -> hypothesis -> enum34 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
pip -> wheel -> setuptools
matplotlib=3.0.0 -> numpy -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
python=3.5 -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools
Package certifi conflicts for:
pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
matplotlib=3.0.0 -> numpy -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
nb_conda -> nb_conda_kernels[version='>=2.0.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> prometheus_client -> twisted -> service_identity -> attrs[version='>=16.0.0'] -> hypothesis -> enum34 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
scipy=1.1.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0,>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
numpy=1.15.2 -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
python=3.5 -> pip -> wheel -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
Package wheel conflicts for:
numpy=1.15.2 -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
nb_conda -> nb_conda_kernels[version='>=2.0.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> prometheus_client -> twisted -> service_identity -> attrs[version='>=16.0.0'] -> hypothesis -> enum34 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
pip -> wheel
python=3.5 -> pip -> wheel
matplotlib=3.0.0 -> numpy -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
scipy=1.1.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0,>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package pip conflicts for:
nb_conda -> nb_conda_kernels[version='>=2.0.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> prometheus_client -> twisted -> service_identity -> attrs[version='>=16.0.0'] -> hypothesis -> enum34 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> pip
matplotlib=3.0.0 -> numpy -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
pip
numpy=1.15.2 -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.5 -> pip
scipy=1.1.0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0,>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0'] -> pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Environment I was trying to set up had a single line that was hanging things up for me, namely

```
conda install -c anaconda nb_conda
```

By walking through each environment requirement line by line I was able to get this to work and didn't have to uninstall or change anything

Answer (score 0):

Apart from base environment create a new environment